# If the shell is running a program, will the shell also receive a SIGINT signal when Ctrl+C is pressed?

Tags: shell, signals, process-groups

I have read that when you press `Ctrl+C`, then a `SIGINT` signal will be sent to the *foreground process group*.

Now the accepted answer in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287044/why-does-bash-ignore-sigint-if-its-currently-running-child-handles-it) says:

> Basically, your signal is received by all foreground processes, ie the
>   shell and the program,

I have executed `cat` within `bash`, and noticed that the `PGID` for `bash` and `cat` are different, so they do not belong to the same process group.

So when you press `Ctrl+C`, only `cat` will receive the `SIGINT` signal (and so the answer I quoted is wrong), am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question is about a bash script. You're running bash interactively. This makes a difference for process groups: that's the whole reason why process groups were invented. The intent of a process group is to capture all the processes that are involved in one interactively-started task. So an interactive shell starts each job in a separate process group, whereas a shell running a script doesn't create new process groups.

Comment: Is the process group identified by the PID of the interactive shell? in other words if `echo $$` returned `432`, would `432` be the identifier for the process group also?

Comment: No, the process group of a job is the PID of the first process in that job. This cannot be the `$$` since it's the original shell process and different processes must have different PIDs.